# Compiling with Gradle from Android Studio doesn't pick up new resource changes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm facing a strange behaviour when trying to compile from Android Studio. If a resource is modified, let's say the content of a string inside strings.xml, the new build won't have the change. Everything is fine and up to date when compiling from the command line. Tried on Android Studio 1.3 and 1.4Preview. Gradle version 2.4.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning & rebuilding your project?

Comment: clean and rebuild does the job but I don't think should be the case when the change is just a string. What I'm looking for is a solution to compile from Android Studio without clean and rebuild every time